# Probability of rolling a 1 and 2 in 4 rolls?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I was working on a problem to compute the variance of the number of distinct roll values after 4 dice rolls and tried approaching it with indicators. I defined $I_n$ to be the indicator random variable of rolling the value $n$ within the 4 rolls. Thus $X$, the number of distinct roll values would be $\sum_{n = 1}^6 I_n$.

Upon calculating $X^2$, I was having trouble calculating $I_nI_m$ where $n \neq m$. I tried using inclusion-exclusion, but didn't really get anywhere. In the end I just brute force calculated all of the cases since there were only 4 rolls.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to calculating this probability for larger number of rolls?

Comment: You might be interested in the Coupn Collector's Problem: in particular, the section on "Calculating the variance" in the Wikipedia article on the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Calculating_the_variance).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I used a different approach

So, I first simplified this with 2 dice. Since there are only 2 possibilities ${1,2}$ and $2,1$, the probability is $\frac1{18}$.

For each time we add a die, the first roll might be:

- $1$, in which case we only need to get a $2$ in the next rolls. The probability of this happening is:

  - $\frac16$
  - $1-\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1}$ for rolling a $2$ at least once, where $n$ is the number of dice *(including the added one)*
  - Multiplying those together gives us a probablity of $\frac16(1-\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1})$.
- $2$, which has the same chance of happening as our first scenario: $\frac16(1-\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1})$
- Something else (greater than $2$), and our chance of getting both $1$ and $2$ in the next rolls is:

  - $\frac23$
  - The chance of getting $1$ and $2$ with 1 less die, or $P(n-1)$.

This gives us the following function $P$:
$P(n)=\frac13(1-\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1})+\frac23P(n-1); n\in\Bbb{N}; n\gt2; P(2)=\frac1{18}$

So:
$P(3)=\frac13(1-\frac{25}{36})+\frac23\cdot\frac1{18} = \frac13\cdot\frac{11}{36}+\frac1{27}=\frac5{36}$
$P(4)=\frac13(1-\frac{125}{216})+\frac23\cdot\frac5{36} = \frac13\cdot\frac{91}{216}+\frac5{54}=\frac{151}{648}$

Hopefully that's correct :)

Comment: I confirmed your answer with the multinomial distribution.  Clearly, your recursion generalizes better than using the multinomial distribution.